# Basic URL Rewriting causing internal server error

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm very new to this and have read a couple of articles on URL rewriting.

http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/

All i want to do is change www.domain.com/single-recipe.php?id=6

To www.domain.com/recipes/6

From the tutorials I have come up with the following code in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule    ^recipes/([0-9]+)/?$    single-recipe.php?id=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle recipe requests
```

When i try to access any page on the site i am greeted with a lovely internal server error 500.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because of the extra space remove it and try :

```
RewriteRule ^recipes/([0-9]+)/?$ single-recipe.php?id=$1[NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed the internal server error. Now when I type in domain.com/recipes/1 I get a 404 /single-recipe.php not found.

Comment: Does the file **single-recipe.php** exist?

Comment: Yes if i go to domain.com/single-recipe?id=1 it loads

Comment: remove `^` in that line and try, `RewriteRule recipes/([0-9]+)/?$ single-recipe.php?id=$1[NC,L]`